Memory Leak in Next.js Application – How to Diagnose and Fix?
I’m facing a memory leak issue in my Next.js project, which builds on React. The problem appears to worsen over time, leading to increased memory usage and performance issues. I suspect the leak may be linked to two areas: a countdown timer component and data integration with Typesense.
Here’s what I’ve observed and attempted so far:
Countdown Timer Component: I noticed timers may still run after the component unmounts. I’ve added cleanup functions with clearInterval inside useEffect, but this hasn’t fully resolved the issue.
Typesense Integration: Memory usage seems to spike when product data updates, especially with large arrays. I implemented a cleanup function to remove items on page change, yet memory isn’t being released as expected.
My questions:
What strategies or tools can I use in Next.js to identify the root cause of a memory leak?
Are there best practices specific to Next.js for managing memory, especially with third-party data sources and timer components?
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with countdowns or Typesense in Next.js, and how did you address it?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Depends if the memory leak is client or server side

So, for the most part, I have everything on the server structure
